# Running a cucumber test in a docker machine breaks my test database

Tags: ruby, database, ubuntu, docker-compose, cucumber

When I run a cucumber test in a docker machine via

```
docker-compose run api bundle exec cucumber features/v1/test.feature
```

The test succeeds but when I run the rspec tests after that there is no more data in the test database and I have to populate it again.

I've tried this several times to check and this happens every time I run a cucumber test. I am working in Ubuntu and I have a postgresql database.

Does running a cucumber test makes a 'reset' of the docker environment in any way?

Comment: Are you using `database_cleaner` ?

Comment: I have it installed but I don't use it when running the feature files

Comment: Can you share the configurations for database_cleaner ? how do you set it

Comment: I'm using it to configure rspec

    ``RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Test::DatabaseHelpers, type: :db
    config.before(type: :db) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.append_after(type: :db) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.around(type: :db) do |example|
        DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
              Api::Current.configure do |current|
              end
              Api::Container.start(:current_context)
              example.run
              end
        end
    end``